# Error: Failed to save connection profile hlfv1

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-composer

I am getting below error while deploying .bna file to hyperledger fabric 1.0 version using hyperledger composer.

**I am using ubuntu 16.04 on aws.**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-220:~/composer-sample-networks/packages/trade-network/dist$ composer network deploy -a trade-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

> Deploying business network from archive: trade-network.bna
>   Business network definition:
>           Identifier: trade-network@0.1.0
>           Description: Commodities Trading Business Network
>
> Error: Failed to save connection profile hlfv1
>   Command failed

Answer (score 1):

Connection profiles are saved to the ~/.composer-connection-profiles/ directory. Ensure that this is writable.